# How to convert PDF with images which I don't care about to text?

Tags: pdf, text, converters, pdftotext

I'm trying to convert pdf to text files. The problem is that those pdf contain images, which I don't care about (this is the type of file I want to extract (https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/pub/media/store/documents/file/l/f/lf_sup_2020_213_fr.pdf). Note that if I do copy/paste with my mouse, it work quite well (except the line break), so I'd guess that it's possible. Most of the answer I found online work pretty well on dummy pdf with text only, but give especially bad result on the map.
For instance, something like this

```
from tika import parser # pip install tika
raw = parser.from_file('test2.pdf')
print(raw['content'])
```

works well for retrieving the text, but I have a lot of trash like this :

> ERY

> CTR

> 3

> CH

> A

which appear because of the map.

Something like this, which work by converting the pdf to images and then reading the images, face the same problem (I found it on a very similar thread on stackoverflow, but there is no answer) :

```
import pytesseract as pt
from PIL import Image
import sys 

def convert(name):
    pages = convert_from_path(name, dpi=200)
    for idx,page in enumerate(pages):
        page.save('page'+str(idx)+'.jpg', 'JPEG')
        quote = Image.open('page'+str(idx)+'.jpg')
        text = pt.image_to_string(quote, lang="fra")
        file_ex = open('page'+str(idx)+'.text',"w")
        file_ex.write(text)
        file_ex.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert(sys.argv[1])
```

Finally, I tried to remove the image first, and then using one of the solutions above, but it didn't work better :

```
from tika import parser # pip install tika
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# Remove the images
inputStream = open("lf_sup_2020_213_fr.pdf", "rb")
outputStream = open("test3.pdf", "wb")

 
src = PdfFileReader(inputStream)
output = PdfFileWriter()
 

[output.addPage(src.getPage(i)) for i in range(src.getNumPages())]
output.removeImages()
 

output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

# Read from pdf without images
raw = parser.from_file('test2.pdf')
print(raw['content'])
```

Do you know how to solve this ? It can be in any language.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you could try is to use a toolkit capable of parsing the text characters in the PDF then use the object properties to try and remove the unwanted map labels while keeping the text characters required.

For example, the [ParsePages](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/pdf/pdfdocument-parsepages.html) method from [LEADTOOLS PDF toolkit](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/products/pdf-pro) (which is what I am familiar with since I work for the vendor of this toolkit) can be used to obtain the text from the PDF:

```
using (PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument(pdfFileName))
{
   PDFParsePagesOptions options = PDFParsePagesOptions.All;
   document.ParsePages(options, 1, -1);

   using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(txtFileName))
   {
      IList<PDFObject> objects = document.Pages[0].Objects;
      writer.WriteLine("Objects: {0}", objects.Count);
      foreach (PDFObject obj in objects)
      {
         if (obj.TextProperties.IsEndOfLine)
            writer.WriteLine(obj.Code);
         else
            writer.Write(obj.Code);
      }
      writer.WriteLine("---------------------");
   }
}
```

This will obtain all the text in the PDF for the first page, with the unwanted results as you mentioned. Here is an excerpt below:

```
Objects: 3918
5
91L
F5
4
1 LF
N
OY
L2
1AM
TService
8
26
1de l’Information 
0
B09SUP AIP 213/20 
7 
Aéronautique
 
Date de publication : 05 NOV 
e-mail  : sia.qualite@aviation-civile.gouv.fr 
Internet  : www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr 
141
 
17˚
82
N20 
9Objet : Création de 4 zones réglementées temporaires (ZRT) pour l’exercice VOLOPS en région de Chambéry 
En vigueur : Du mercredi 25 Novembre 2020 au vendredi 04 décembre 2020
```

More code can be used to examine the properties for each parsed character:

```
writer.WriteLine("  ObjectType: {0}", obj.ObjectType.ToString());
writer.WriteLine("  Bounds: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", obj.Bounds.Left, obj.Bounds.Top, obj.Bounds.Right, obj.Bounds.Bottom);
writer.WriteLine("  TextProperties.FontHeight: {0}", obj.TextProperties.FontHeight.ToString());
writer.WriteLine("  TextProperties.FontIndex: {0}", obj.TextProperties.FontIndex.ToString());
writer.WriteLine("  Code: {0}", obj.Code);
writer.WriteLine("------");
```

This will give the properties for each character:

```
  Objects: 3918
  ObjectType: Text
  Bounds: -60.952693939209, 1017.25231933594, -51.8431816101074, 1023.71826171875
  TextProperties.FontHeight: 7.10454273223877
  TextProperties.FontIndex: 48
  Code: 5
------
```

Using these properties, the unwanted text might be filtered using their properties. For example, I noticed that the FontHeight for a good portion of the unwanted text is around 7 PDF units, so the first code might be altered to avoid extracting any text smaller than 7.25 PDF units:

```
foreach (PDFObject obj in objects)
{
   if (obj.TextProperties.FontHeight > 7.25)
   {
      if (obj.TextProperties.IsEndOfLine)
         writer.WriteLine(obj.Code);
      else
         writer.Write(obj.Code);
   }
}
```

The extracted output would give a better result, an excerpt follows:

```
Objects: 3918
Service
de l’Information 
SUP AIP 213/20 
 
Aéronautique
Date de publication : 05 NOV 
e-mail  : sia.qualite@aviation-civile.gouv.fr 
Internet  : www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr 
 
Objet : Création de 4 zones réglementées temporaires (ZRT) pour l’exercice VOLOPS en région de Chambéry 
En vigueur : Du mercredi 25 Novembre 2020 au vendredi 04 décembre 2020 
 
Lieu : FIR : Marseille LFMM - AD : Chambéry Aix-Les-Bains LFLB, Chambéry Challes les Eaux LFLE 
 
ZRT LE SIRE, MOTTE CASTRALE, ALLEVARD 
*
C
D
E
```

In the end, you will have to try and come up with a good criteria to filter out the unwanted text without removing the text you need to keep, using this approach.